# Retrying a Spring Data Flow task while still changing properies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

It's my understanding that to retry a Spring DataFlow composed task, you can't change the properties (like Spring Batch does).

However, it's possible that the value of one of the properties is somehow 'wrong' and we need to change it to have any hope of the task ever running again.

We'd like to truly relaunch the existing task, but while changing the a property, and still have the behavior where the composed task will pick up where it left off (i.e., start from failed section of the flow).

Is this possible?

We are using Spring Data Flow 2.0.0.m2.

Thanks!

Comment: Ooo! SCDF just released 2.0.0.RC1!  Ok, soon we'll be using that :)

Comment: How are you relaunching the CTR, is it via the `Restart Job` under the Jobs Tab?

Comment: Well, we are using the API that services the 'Restart the Job' option under the Jobs tab.  And from that API, you can't change the properties.  We are assuming/designing on the basis that you can not.